# Get Meta Description Tag of a Page

Tags: meta-tags

I want to get the meta description of a page and pass it on as a parameter to another function. Something similar to get_post_meta() in WordPress where you can get the meta values after you pass the page id or the node id.
I've searched and all I could find is a function to add meta ( drupal_add_html_head ) but nothing to get meta data. Thanks in advance for your time.